# Getting user details from Azure AD Application Proxy authentication

Tags: reactjs, authentication, asp.net-core-3.1, azure-application-proxy

I have made a .Net core API with a React front end, which is being hosted on an IIS box, which I don't control. The root directory has been set up to authenticate using Azure AD Application Proxy, which is working fine for authentication. My question is, is it possible for me to extract basic user details (name, email address) from this type of authentication, either through React or the .Net application and, if so, how? I've done a lot of googling and can't seem to find anything relevant.

I've noticed there's a cookie set called AzureAppProxyAccessCookie_ which sounds like it could be useful, but I can't find any reference as to how it could be used for this.

Answer (score 0):

You're likely looking for header-based authentication: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-au/azure/active-directory/app-proxy/application-proxy-configure-single-sign-on-with-headers

Setting can be found in the Azure AAD portal under "Enterprise Applications" ->  -> "Single sign-on". [Screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDtzw.png)